# To run qdap, why must I repeatedly install gtools with dependencies = T?

Tags: r, installation, qdap

I have installed the packages `qdap` [2.2.0] and `gtools` [Ver. 3.4.1] which `qdap` requires.  But loading them with `library()` fails, until I reinstall gtools each time with the argument `dependencies = TRUE`.  What am I doing wrong and not understanding?

```
> library(qdap)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘gtools’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘qdap’ was built under R version 3.1.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’
> library(gtools)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘gtools’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘gtools’ was built under R version 3.1.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gtools’
> 
> install.packages("gtools", dependencies = T)
```

Comment: I suspect there's a java issue or recognition issue.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker, thank you.  I run XLConnect all the time, which relies on Java, and have had no issues other than some about memory sufficiency.  What is a "recognition issue" and how can I understand it and alleviate it?  I copied gtools into the directory where all my R packages reside.  And I use qdap all the time for text mining so I would like to get to the root of this (no pun intended).

Comment: In a fresh session of R can you load gtools without loading qdap?

Comment: @TylerRinker: I started afresh and both loaded perfectly.  I started again with my sourced suite of packages loaded first but even then both gtools and qdap loaded perfectly, which I tried in either order.  I feel a bit foolish now, but I have encountered exactly the errors shown above repeatedly.  Just can't reproduce them now.  I apologize for perhaps wasting your time.  Still, my strong belief is that the gremlin will rear its head somewhere.  I will then look at all packages loaded and conflicts.  Thank you for your time, unless you have another suggestion.

Comment: not at all a problem.  "architecture" indicates some mismatch in java type 64 vs 86 as I've seemed a related error regarding rJava tht I've documented here: http://trinker.github.io/qdap_dev/vignettes/qdap_vignette.html#install  If something happens again fee free to open an issue on GitHub and we'll work through it.

Comment: I posted what I just learned as an answer so that hopefully it will help others.

Comment: The problem has continued, and from this discussion thread [aggressive Spy Hunter 4 thinks gtools is infected with Gator](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/gtools-Gator-infected-td4725886.html) I gather the problem is not Java and certainly not Tyler Rinker's package. The problem is that Spy Hunter 4 removes gtools each time it runs as it somehow concludes that gtools.dll is an infection of Gator. Enigma Software, who licenses Spy Hunter, is at 855-432-0727 and perhaps they can loosen up a bit on their software so that the R package survives once it is installed.